# Is it safe to use "Use for Development" on my only iPad?

Tags: xcode

This one is border-line for whether it belongs here, but I think SO is the best place to ask.

Apple has pretty consistently warned that any iDevice you flag for development in Xcode should NOT be used for regular day-in/day-out use. It should be an 'extra' phone/tablet you've set aside for development/testing purposes only.

But is this really the case? As long as I'm not running beta OS builds, is there any harm to using my only iPad (which my wife needs to use as well) for development?

I'd rather not have to buy a second iPad if I don't have to, but I also don't want to cause any problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only 1 cell phone (iPhone) and 1 iPad, both are my main ("non-Development") devices, but I still use both for "Development" purposes.  I also used them for Beta iOS 5, which broke them a few times and I was without a cell phone for a few days.  In my opinion, it is safe to use your main devices for development ***IF*** you understand that something can go wrong (brick) at any time.  Not installing beta iOS's is also a good idea, but nothing/no one can guarantee that a "Development" device will work when/how you expect it to.

<sub>btw, this question will probably be migrated to programmers.se or apple.se.</sub>

Comment: Unlike chown I have never installed a iOS beta on my iPod touch or iPad, but I have used them for development for some time. I have never had a problem with either.